# C# vs C++ pass by reference handling

Tags: c#, c++, comparison, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Here is the question in book:

In functions, what is the difference of passing a parameter by-value and by-reference? State one advantage that c# ha compared with c++ in the way passing by reference is handled.

I know the difference of passing a parameter by-value and by-reference but what advantage have c# compared with c++?

Comment: If this is homework, then you should tag your question as such. In any case, the idea that C# has any advantage here is completely subjective (I certainly disagree), so there is no right answer.

Comment: C# compared to C++ is the same as car compared to carpet (c)

Comment: It's a pretty valid question, and I am looking forward to knowing the answer as well. Why the votes to close?

Comment: @xbonez : Because the question invalidly presupposes that C# has some innate advantage over C++ when it comes to argument passing.

Comment: @ildjarn can't some programs have advantage over others? Or its wrong that C# has advantage over C++ passing by reference?

Comment: @Loclip : C# always uses reference semantics for reference types; C++ lets you choose what semantics you want. They're different, neither is "better", but the C++ approach gives the programmer more control.

Comment: @ildjarn i just wanted to know... thanks for answer..

Comment: @ildjarn Value types vs. reference types and pass by value vs. pass by reference are orthogonal concepts in C#. You can pass references by value or by reference, and you can pass values by value or by reference.

Comment: @FredOverflow : Okay, I'll bite -- how does one pass a reference type by value?

Comment: By not using the `ref` keyword. If you have a function `void function(string s)` and you call it like `function(x)`, then `s` will be a copy of `x`, so assignments to `s` won't change `x`. If you want assignments to `s` to also affect `x`, you have to write `void function(ref string s)` instead.

Comment: @FredOverflow : You're using an immutable type to prove that value semantics exist? Try `StringBuilder`, and modifications to that object, and get back to me. ;-]

Comment: But I'm not talking about modifying an object, I'm talking about assigning to a variable. It doesn't matter if the objects are mutable or immutable. If you have a function `void function(object o)` and you assign to `o`, the client reference will be unaffected by that assignment.

Comment: Also, `string` doesn't have value semantics. It's a reference type.

Comment: @FredOverflow : I'm confounded by your responses here. If I pass a `foo` in C++ I get a copy due to value semantics; I need to pass a `foo&` in order to mutate the passed-in object. If I pass a `foo` in C#, and `foo` is a reference type, I can mutate that object; there is no concept of value semantics. No one is talking about reseating objects, we're talking about value vs. reference semantics.

Comment: Loclip is asking about **passing** by value vs. **passing** by reference, and you are talking about value **semantics** vs. reference **semantics**. I was just pointing out that those are orthogonal in C#: `void value_by_value(some_struct a)`, `void value_by_reference(ref some_struct b)`, `void reference_by_value(some_class c)`, `void reference_by_reference(ref some_class d)`. Do you agree or disagree with that?

Comment: The only difference I can see between these two functions `void foo(T & x)` (C++) and `void foo(ref T x)` (C#) is that the latter requires the use of the `ref` keyword when calling the function: `T val = new T(); foo(ref val);`. This can be seen as an advantage as it makes it clear at the call site that the argument might be modified, which is not the case in C++ where you need to look at the function signature to have this information.

Comment: I think the fact that the word "reference" can refer to so many different concepts is one of the more unfortunate accidents in modern programming.

Comment: Found answer: C++ includes a special kind of pointer type called a reference type that is used primarily for formal parameters. Advantages of both pass-by-reference and pass-by-value. Java extends C++’s reference variables and allows them to replace pointers entirely. References are references to objects, rather than being addresses. C# includes both the references of Java and the pointers of C++

Answer (score 0):

Because the syntax changes, it doesn't change the concept.

That being said the only 'advantage' C# would have is the syntax is 'cleaner' in the sense you don't need to know all the pointer reference and dereference syntax `& * ->`

Comment: @Cole : Are you sure you understand what a reference is in C++?

Comment: @ildjarn "pointer is dangerous and subtle because a deallocated memory region may contain the same data as it did before it was deallocated but may be then reallocated and overwritten by unrelated code"

Comment: @Cole : The topic is references, not pointers.

Comment: @ildjarn: Same thing is true for dangling references as wild pointers.

Comment: @Ben : I don't see how that's entirely relevant -- the topic is passing arguments by reference, not returning by reference.

Comment: @ildjarn: One can return a parameter passed by reference.  Or bind a class member reference to a parameter passed by reference.  Either one can dangle.

Comment: @Ben : Yes, yes, pedantry. In single-threaded code that properly avoids `new`/`delete` when it can, I find it hard to imagine this occurring in practice.

Comment: @ildjarn: Absolutely.  Good coding practices prevent dangling references and wild pointers alike.  (Although e.g. resizing a `std::vector` also invalidates existing references).  The point is simply that your objection "we're talking about references, not pointers", makes absolutely zero difference as to safety.

Comment: @Ben : But safety was brought up neither in the question nor this answer; it was brought up only in a more-or-less tangential comment, in a way that doesn't relate to the question (IMO). In that way, it's off-topic, and that was my apparently-unclear way of saying so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11901/discussion-between-ben-voigt-and-ildjarn)

Comment: @Ben : Not to be rude, but I'd rather not. ;-[

Comment: @ildjarn: I hate that move to chat link, since I tend to click on it before I even see it's there.

Comment: Found answer: C++ includes a special kind of pointer type called a reference type that is used primarily for formal parameters. Advantages of both pass-by-reference and pass-by-value. Java extends C++’s reference variables and allows them to replace pointers entirely. References are references to objects, rather than being addresses. C# includes both the references of Java and the pointers of C++